# Zoom to non-geometric layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, zoom

In QGIS, I have a non-geometric (layer A) layer which is joined to a geometric layer (layer B).
I can easily search in layer A, but I can't zoom to the found feature. I want QGIS to zoom to the relevant feature in layer B, when I want to zoom to a layer A feature.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can do this?